# Why does Apple's doc say that you don't call the superclass's event handling methods in subclass of UIView?

Tags: iphone

In Apple's document, Event Handling Guide for iOS, the section "[Best Practices for Handling Multitouch Events](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW18)":

```
If you handle events in a subclass of UIView, UIViewController, or (in rare cases) UIResponder, 
  You should implement all of the event-handling methods (even if it is a null implementation).
  Do not call the superclass implementation of the methods.
```

and

```
If you handle events in a subclass of any other UIKit responder class,
  You do not have to implement all of the event-handling methods.
  But in the methods you do implement, be sure to call the superclass implementation.
```

Why? I don't understand the rationale behind point 2 of both cases. Doesn't it depend on the different situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably relates to the later point:

> Do not explicitly send events up the responder (via nextResponder); instead, invoke the superclass implementation and let the UIKit handle responder-chain traversal.

If you handle touchesBegan:withEvent: and touchesEnded:withEvent:, what does UIView do with touchesMoved:withEvent:? Is it supposed to forward it up the responder chain?

Comment: I added another case(subclass of any other UIKit responder class). Doesn't your explanation also apply to the added case?